# Update table cell's when condition is fulfilled

Tags: sql

Let's say I have table with following cells in my table

```
| subject | amount |
|    math | 40     |
```

Periodically I want to update "amount" with new figure but I want update be done only if new figure is bigger then the old one. Can it be done with one single SQL request?

Comment: You task is not clear. Where the *replacement* values are coming from? Is there another table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
update myTable
set amount = @NewAmount
where subject = 'math' and amount < @NewAmount
```

[you don't say where the new values are coming from. Are they in another table? If so, a join to the other table will be required.]